# How can I have custom result with autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails-2

In view:

```
<%= text_field_with_auto_complete :vendor, :number, {}, {:with => "'vendor[number]=' + $('vendor_number').value"} %>
```

In Controller:

```
auto_complete_for :vendor, :number do |vendors, params|
  vendors.vendor_company_filter(params[:company_id])
end
```

It works fine, gives list of vendor number as a result
but I need "vendor name + vendor number" in a result list, how can I achieve this..??
please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found an easy way,
in Controller

```
def auto_complete_for_vendor_number
  @vendors = Vendor.find_by_number(number)
  render :partial => 'auto_complete_for_vendor_number'
end
```

in _auto_complete_for_vendor_number.html.eb partial:

```
<ul>
  <% @vendors. each do |vendor|  %>
    <li><%= vendor.name+'('+vendor.number+')' %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

It worked fine :)